# Problema con método asíncrono

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Sucede que quiero ejecutar un método asíncrono que me realice varias consultas a SQL Server pero me saca error.

Método asíncrono:

```vb
''' <summary>
''' Este metodo obtiene toda la data  de la base  datos
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Async Function BuscarDatosBd_Principal() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Entornodatos = New Dictionary(Of String, DataTable)
    Dim var As Boolean = False
    Dim Oldconexion As String = Cnn.ConnectionString
    If Aplicacion.SysApp.Leerconexion = False Then
        Return False
    End If
    set_conexion(Aplicacion.SysApp._Laconexion)
    Dim Partidas = Aplicacion.SysApp._Laconexion.Split(";")
Try
    If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable() Then 'Si tengo Internet
        var = True
        Entornodatos.Clear()
        ''Verificar si el servidor esta disponibble
        If abriconexion() Then
            ''Extraigo las Categorias
            Dim strsql As String = String.Format("SELECT tfuente.codcat, tfuente.categoria, tfuente.lista_opcional, tfuente.es_venta, tfuente.codempresa, " _
                                    + "tfuente.pide_deta," _
                                    + "cant_productos=(select count(*) from  dbsisflex_data.dbo.inven inven with (nolock) where inven.codempresa=tfuente.codempresa and inven.codcat=tfuente.codcat) " _
                                    + "FROM  dbsisflex_data.dbo.catego  tfuente " _
                                    + "where codempresa='{0}'" _
                                    + "and tfuente.es_venta=1", Codempresa)
            ''Varible de datatable
            Dim datatable As DataTable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("categorias", datatable)
            End If
            strsql = ""
            datatable = New DataTable
            ''Extraigo las comisio
            strsql = String.Format("SELECT t.coddoc, t.numero, t.codclte, cl.razonsoc, d.documento,  t.codvende, t.codclasi, t.codmoneda, t.tipo_trans, t.referencia, t.orden_no, t.ncf_secuencia,   t.f_mov, " _
            + "t.origen, t.valor, t.balance, t.valor_otramoneda, t.descuento, t.cgcontrol, t.dias_cre, t.factor_mul, t.usuario, t.comision," _
            + "t.no_cliente, t.f_fac, t.banco, t.tasa, t.codempresa, t.ref_coddoc, t.ref_numero, t.codmodulo, t.id_reg, t.selectivo " _
            + "FROM  dbsisflex_data.dbo.cxcmov t join dbsisflex_data.dbo.documen d on t.codempresa=d.codempresa and t.coddoc=d.coddoc " _
            + "left outer join dbsisflex_data.dbo.clientes cl on t.codempresa=cl.codempresa and t.codclte=cl.codclte " _
            + "where t.codempresa='{0}' " _
            + "and d.es_cxc=1 and t.balance<>0 " _
            + "and (t.codvende ='{1}' or cl.codvende='{1}')", Codempresa, Codvende)
            datatable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("comisio", datatable)
            End If
            strsql = ""
            datatable = New DataTable
            ''Extraigo las CLIENTES
            strsql = String.Format("SELECT codclte, razonsoc, e_mail, contacto, direccion, direccion2, sector, telefono, telefono1, codvende, dueno, longitud, latitud, geo_coordenada, cal_tax, descuento, " _
            + "balance, limite, dias_cre, tipo_dato, limite_fac, dia_visi, Cant_visitas_mes, orden_visi, nivel_precio, codempresa, nota, codmoneda, id_reg " _
            + "FROM  dbsisflex_data.dbo.clientes with (nolock) " _
            + "where codempresa='{0}'" _
            + "and (codvende ='{1}')   " _
            + "and estatus=1", Codempresa, Codvende)
            datatable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("clientes", datatable)
            End If

            strsql = ""
            datatable = New DataTable
            ''Extraigo las INVEN
            strsql = String.Format("SELECT codart, articulo, articulo2, detalle, inven.lista_opcional, codund, inven.codcat, codtart, codmarca, codmoneda, codmuestra, inven.pide_deta, excento_it, costo_vxformula, " _
            + "impuesto, inven.descuento, precio, precio_lim, existencia + existenciab, marca, cod_barra, peso_lbs, es_combo, precio1, precio2, precio4, precio3, precio5, precio6," _
            + "precio7, precio8, precio9, precio10, unds_enva, inven.codempresa, nocambiarprecio, p_alto, p_ancho, p_largo, p_oferta, formula, es_formulado, cant_defa," _
            + "selectivo " _
            + "FROM  dbsisflex_data.dbo.inven inven with (nolock) join dbsisflex_data.dbo.catego catego with (nolock) on inven.codempresa=catego.codempresa and inven.codcat =catego.codcat" _
            + "where inven.codempresa='{0}' and catego.es_venta=1 and inven.activo=1 ", Codempresa)
            datatable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("inven", datatable)
            End If

            strsql = ""
            datatable = New DataTable
            ''Extraigo las combos
            strsql = String.Format("SELECT  codcomb, descrip, sal_auto, f_inicial, f_final, precio, codempresa FROM  dbsisflex_data.dbo.combos combos    where  codempresa='{0}' and combos.codcomb<>''", Codempresa)
            datatable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("combos", datatable)
            End If

            strsql = ""
            datatable = New DataTable
            ''Extraigo las ofertas
            strsql = String.Format("SELECT codart, codempresa, codcomb, codclte, cant_gratis, boletos, oferta_general,  precio, cantidad    FROM  dbsisflex_data.dbo.ofertas ofer   where ofer.codempresa='{0}' and ofer.codart<>''", Codempresa)
            datatable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("ofertas", datatable)
            End If

            strsql = ""
            datatable = New DataTable
            ''Extraigo las ofertados
            strsql = String.Format("SELECT codart,  cantidad, por_desc, codcomb, precio, costo, ctotal, codempresa, id_reg, cargo_directo, codtipo_costo, gratis, codetapa, base " _
                   + "FROM  dbsisflex_data.dbo.ofertados ofer   where ofer.codempresa='{0}' and ofer.codart<>'' and codcomb<>''", Codempresa)
            datatable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("ofertados", datatable)
            End If
            datatable = New DataTable
            ''Extraigo las clientes_productos
            strsql = String.Format("select t.codempresa, t.codclte, razonsoc=  max(cl.razonsoc), t.codart, articulo=max(pr.articulo), max(t.f_mov) as f_ult_compra, " _
            + "vendido=sum(t.cantidad*t.signo), precio_min=min(t.cantidad), precio_min=max(t.cantidad)  " _
            + "from dbsisflex_data.dbo.invtran t join dbsisflex_data.dbo.clientes cl with (nolock) on t.codempresa=cl.codempresa and t.codclte=cl.codclte" _
            + "join dbsisflex_data.dbo.inven pr with (nolock) on t.codempresa= pr.codempresa and t.codart =pr.codart " _
            + "join dbsisflex_data.dbo.documen d with (nolock) on t.codempresa=d.codempresa and t.coddoc =d.coddoc " _
            + "where (t.codempresa='{0}' " _
            + "and t.f_mov between dateadd(mm, -24, getdate()) and  getdate() " _
            + "and t.origen in ('D','C')) " _
            + "and (t.codvende ='{1}' or cl.codvende='{1}') " _
            + "and d.es_venta=1 " _
            + "group by t.codempresa, t.codclte,  t.codart " _
            + "order by t.codempresa, t.codclte, t.codart ", Codempresa, Codvende)
            datatable = Ejecutar_Consulta(strsql)
            ''Verifico que tenga algo
            If datatable IsNot Nothing AndAlso datatable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Entornodatos.Add("clientes_productos", datatable)
            End If

        End If

    End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex)
    End Try
    Return var
    'Seteo la anterior conexion
    set_conexion(Oldconexion)
End Function
```

De esta manera lo ejecuto:

```
Await Task.Run(Async Function() Await BuscarDatosBd_Principal())
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Buenas @Davlio este es el error que que me sale gracias  `Public Async Function Ejecutar() As Task
        Try
            If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then
                Await Task.Run(Async Function() Await BuscarDatosBd_Principal())
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function`  **Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero:

Cuando se escribe un método asíncrono, en tu caso `Private Async Function BuscarDatosBd_Principal() As Task(Of Boolean)`, para que se compile correctamente, en el cuerpo del método, debería haber por lo menos una llamada await a otro método o a un `await Task.Run(()=>{.....})`.

Segundo:

La manera en como llamas o ejecutas tu método `Await Task.Run(Async Function() Await BuscarDatosBd_Principal())`. No es necesario que utilices el factory `Task.Run`, ya que tu método es ya asíncrono. Tan solo bastaria con "await Método".